# Не запускается чужой проект

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Не запускается чужой проект, вроде просто копирую исходные файлы, запихиваю код и при компиляции выдает:

> Error 1   error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt   d:\FTP\program\tpr_2\tpr_2\LINK tpr_2

Бинарник работает нормально, который идет в комплекте, как запустить этот проект? Пробовал на 3-ех компах с разными вижлами, не запускается, разные версии Нета и релиз режим тоже не дали эффекта. Заранее спасибо.

[Ссылка на проект](http://code-live.ru/post/simplex-method-cpp/)

Comment: После манипуляций отсюда http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/error-link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-inval
получаю такие ошибки:
Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall simplex::gen_plane(void)" (?gen_plane@simplex@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _wmain \tpr_2.obj
Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall simplex::init(void)" (?init@simplex@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _wmain \tpr_2.obj
....(тут еще одна ошибка с функцией user_data
Error error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals tpr_2.exe

Answer (score 1):

Either disable incremental linking, by going to

Project Properties 
   -> Configuration Properties 
       -> Linker (General) 
          -> Enable Incremental Linking -> "No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)"
or install VS2010 SP1.

Comment: It is inactive 
http://i7.pixs.ru/storage/5/5/6/Skrinshot2_6816315_11306556.png

Comment: http://i7.pixs.ru/storage/5/9/5/Skrinshot2_9630463_11306595.png
I did this, but there isn't "Linker"
Visual Studio 2010